# Do anyone know a good commercial system for sending service notification emails?

Tags: email, alerts

Once in a while we all have a need for sending email notifications to our customers about disturbances of different kinds. For the moment we are using plain email for this, because our email ticketing system doesn't really lend itself to sending lots of email out.

What we are looking for would ideally be a system that could hold different groups of email contacts, and email templates so we could fill in the relevant information.

This should ideally run on the provider's servers, with SLA. Ideally we would have a reliable way to send email notifications even if all our locations were nuked.

Anyone know a system that would work?

Answer (score 2):

For event notifications, you could consider Amazon's Simple Notification Service:

http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Each message can hold up to 8 KB of data.  It's a pub/sub model: you publish messages to the service using signed web requests, and it delivers messages to your subscribers using HTTP or e-mail.  I wrote a client to generate these signatures recently and it wasn't hard; Amazon also publishes some libraries you could use.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/). They allow you to send newsletters and what not, but they sound like they would fit the bill: create lists of different groups, create templates and fill in any information you might need. They would handle the sending as well.

My second suggestion is [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/). They are more used for transactional and notification emails but do have support for templates.

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Let me know if you have any questions.)

Comment: We moved from BlueHornet to MailChimp (for sending marketing information).  We had a couple issues during the transition (mainly staff training and limits to the number of public groups) but overall it was a good move for us. I believe it is free for under a couple thousand subscribers.  Most of the managed email services let the users maintain their own contact info which should save you time.